# Query filter delphi firedac Firebird database

Tags: sql, delphi, firebird, firedac

I´m migrating a database from SQLITE to Firebird,  but now my query doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a reason?

```
frmDados.Clientes.Close();   
frmDados.Clientes.SQL.Text := 
    'SELECT * FROM CLIENTES ' +
    'WHERE  (nomecliente like  :d1) '+
    'order by nomecliente asc';   
frmDados.Clientes.Params.ParamByName('d1').AsString := '%' + Edit1.text + '%';

frmDados.Clientes.OpenOrExecute();
```

Comment: No only filter avething Like if i have a letter " abcd" i write A and don`t filter it i Write C it will filter. NOMECLIENTE      VARCHAR(80),

Comment: "my query don't work" is not a useful problem description. Please [edit] your question and explain *how* it does not work. Do you get the wrong results? Do you get an error? If you want help in solving a problem, *explain the problem you're having specifically*.

Comment: And if you write the same query (filling in the parameter) in your management tool, does it give you the results that you expect ? Anyway, I would not personally choose Firebird these days (if ever).

Comment: Hi the problem is :
Searching for :
"El Corte Inglés" if i writte "el" will return nothing if i writte "El" or "Co" it will returne the datarecord. is there a way to seach if it is captal or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebird dose not support case insensitive queries.

[Query_Case_Insensitive.html](http://mc-computing.com/Databases/delphi/Firebird/Query_Case_Insensitive.html)

Consider these options

```
select * from "abc_table" where "Some_Field" = 'Abc'

select * from "abc_table" where "Some_Field" like 'Abc'

select * from "abc_table" where "Some_Field" containing 'Abc'

select * from "abc_table" where upper("Some_Field") = 'ABC'
```

Equals (=) and ***like** * both perform case sensitive matches
***containing** * is case insensitive, but will also match 'abcd'
upper() works, but will not use an index and, therefore, will read every record in the table
Equals (=) is the fastest because it uses an index (if available)

Comment: As this is the case but how can i do in my case . Have a Upper case field? or can i filter?

Comment: @ml. : look [here caseinsensitivesearch](http://www.destructor.de/firebird/caseinsensitivesearch.htm)

Comment: Firebird does support case insensitive queries (even indexed), if you use a case insensitive collation.